# Unity3d Navmesh agent not connecting

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I try to get a navmesh in my game. It works great only one problem. In 1 of my houses the navmesh doesnt connect propperly. is there a way to work around this? I can make a  few squares and use them as navmesh but I rather do it cleanly[image]

Comment: Are you using `NavMeshComponent` [link](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your baked agent properties. It looks like your radius or height is too big to go trough the door or step is too small to go trough door sill

[image]

Comment: it was the radius. thank you :D